# Where does the react_native_debugger-setup.exe install the React Native Debugger?

Tags: react-native, debugging, react-native-debugger

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly...The react_native_debugger-setup.exe from [here](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases) is installing the React Native Debugger as a program on my computer, right? Until now I always ran the setup file if I wanted to start the debugger. But I don't think that this is the right approach to start it. Is the react_native_debugger-setup.exe installing a program on my Windows 10 computer, which I can start and where does the .exe live, that starts the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the exe under `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\react_native_debugger\app-0.10.10`.